# missing parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle

So I created the following code:

```
Select c_id, c_name 
From bk_CustWithOrders 
where to_char(order_date,'MM-YYYY')=prevMonth(sysdate '2014-11-27', 4)
INTERSECT 
Select c_id, c_name 
From bk_CustWithOrders 
where to_char(order_date,'MM-YYYY')=prevMonth(sysdate '2014-11-27', 3)
INTERSECT 
Select c_id, c_name 
From bk_CustWithOrders
where to_char(order_date,'MM-YYYY')=prevMonth(sysdate '2014-11-27', 2);
```

and I get the following error message:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 55
```

I've tried adding parenthesis but then I incur another error. Not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't know PL/SQL, but have you tried putting spaces between your `)` and `=` characters? Maybe it's interpreting `)=` as something else.

Comment: Think you have to use sysdate `or` a fix date in `prevMonth` not both

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anyting about the function `prevMonth`.

But, What I noticed is there is no separator between sysdate and '2014-11-27'.

`prevMonth(sysdate '2014-11-27', 2);`

Use **','** between `sysdate and '2014-11-27'` and recheck:

`prevMonth(sysdate, '2014-11-27', 2);`
else you have to use any one of `sysdate or '2014-11-27'`

`prevMonth(sysdate, 2);`

```
prevMonth('2014-11-27', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 3, column 55 is exactly at start of this part:

'2014-11-27', 4)

He's saying : I don't understand why you put a whitespace as separator.

Answer (score 0):

`sysdate '2014-11-27'` is invalid.

If you only want to specify a date literal, it should be: `date '2014-11-27'`

`sysdate` is a function that returns the current date. If you just want to pass the current date to the function, then use **only** `sysdate`.